# Polymer 3.0 - Two way calculated binding

Tags: data-binding, polymer-3.x

Is there a way I can use a two way data binding and transform the value before

- setting it to or
- getting it from

a property?

---

I tried by using a computed binding the way it is described [here](https://polymer-library.polymer-project.org/3.0/docs/devguide/data-binding#annotated-computed), but as far as I can see this works only in one direction. I imagine something like having a setter and getter that I can pass to the data binding.

Thank you already!

Comment: Try to add some code you tried so far.